# How to convert military time to 4 digit standard time using mysql query?

Tags: mysql

So here is my code so far:

```
select TIME_FORMAT(s.start_time, '%r') as 'starting'
```

My time in the database is 24hr format so i converted it to standard time (success). However its output is: 02:15:00 PM, how can i make it 02:15 PM and trim the 2 zeros in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> select time_format('14:15:00', '%h:%i %p');
> ```
>
> ```
> | time_format('14:15:00', '%h:%i %p') |
> | :---------------------------------- |
> | 02:15 PM                            |
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fb6a77914eec5cd8f11baf02eae9542a)*

Answer (score 0):

Use date_format instead and %p option.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(s.start_time, '%H:%i %p') as 'starting' from tbl s
```